# How to take spatiotemporal average?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm quite new working with Google Earth Engine. I want to use it to calculate a spatiotemporal average of US States over some years using ERA5 Daily aggregates dataset.

Is there a difference between (1) taking the mean of all images and then taking an average of a shape of this mean image
vs.
(2) taking a spatial average of a shape on each image and then averaging these averages?

If I take a 1 year average there seems to be a discrepancy of about .02 to .5 degrees K between method 1 and 2. Are method 1 and 2 mathematically the same and do I have mistake in my code? If they are different which method should I use?

https://code.earthengine.google.com/9d24c9f93199f63498320d4ff16acd22

```
var adminUnits=ee.FeatureCollection(
   'FAO/GAUL_SIMPLIFIED_500m/2015/level1');

var tMax = ERA5Daily.select(["maximum_2m_air_temperature"]); 

var USStates = adminUnits.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME', 'United States of America'))
.filter([
    ee.Filter.neq('ADM1_NAME', 'Alaska'), 
    ee.Filter.neq('ADM1_NAME', 'Hawaii')]) ;
Map.addLayer(USStates);

var imgcol = tMax.filterDate('2006-01-01', '2007-01-01');

var ftcol = imgcol.map(function(img){
  return img.reduceRegions({
  collection : USStates,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale : 27830
})}).flatten();


var meanImg = imgcol.mean()

var temporoSpatialMean = meanImg.reduceRegions({
  collection : USStates,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale:27830
})

print(temporoSpatialMean)
var varsWanted = ["system:index", "ADM0_NAME",
"ADM1_NAME",
"mean"];

Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: ftcol, 
    description: "US_states_mean_temp_hotdays", 
    folder: 'EE', 
    fileNamePrefix: 'US_states_mean_temp_hotdays', 
    fileFormat: 'CSV',
    selectors : varsWanted
});
```

Comment: "Best" questions are generally *off-topic* here due to their subjective nature. Please [Edit] the Question to contain the code in the Question body.